# SimpleModal - Using several links on one page to open modals with different content

Tags: javascript, simplemodal

Im working on a website for a dental practice. There is a staff page which has thumbnails of individual staff members. I would like to design the page so that when I click on a staff member informations about them and their qualifications appear. Obviously each staff member has a different profile so how do I go about doing this

I've spent ages messing around with the DIV ID's and the basic.js file with no luck.

Many Thanks

**Edit (Technology currently used):**
Simplemodal

Comment: Can you please clarify that this question is regarding SimpleModal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit this answer is for using JQuery & JQuery-UI**

First I will point out the tool we will be using to make a dialog:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Next a few helper functions to make your life easier:

```
$(function(){
    $(".jqy-modal").each(function () {
        $(this).dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: "925px", modal: true, title: $(this).attr("data") });
    });

    $(".auto-wire-dialog").click(function () {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("data")).dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Next lets cover what your html will look like:

```
<a href="#" class="auto-wire-dialog" data="JimBobProfile">Dr. Jim Bob</a>

<div id="JimBobProfile" class="jqy-modal" data="Dr Jim Bob">
    <!-- Info here!!! -->
</div>
```

Finally to understand the concept:

the class of auto-wire-dialog can be put on ANY clickable element.  When that element is clicked it will open the associated dialog with the ID that is specified in the data="..." attribute.

the class of jqy-modal can ONLY be put on a div tag.  That is what creates your modal / dialog window.  You can put a data element on it to specify the title!

You do this for each person, element to trigger the dialog and the dialog itself which will be hidden until it is triggered.

Comment: If you -1 PUT WHY YOU bumped down.  This solution provides a clear answer, and syntax that works to solve the issue.  Do not bump down WITHOUT giving reasoning.

Comment: I down voted your answer because it was to use a different solution. Responding to a question about "plugin a" with an answer to use "plugin b" does not seem useful, IMO.

Comment: "...so how do I go about doing this" The question was asked for how to do it, not how do I use "Plug-in A to do this". My answer did not deserve the bump down.

Comment: Since you may not have realized that the question was, in fact, about SimpleModal (see the tag and reference to basic.js), I'll go ahead and un-down vote your answer. Sorry for my over-reaction.

Comment: Looks like you have to edit your answer before I can remove the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

The following SO answer might lead you in the right direction:

[Multiple calls with Simple Modal OSX Style Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129006/multiple-calls-with-simple-modal-osx-style-dialog/2258297#2258297)

You'll want to create separate div's with the staff member information and then using the JS example in the link I provided, programatically match up the thumbnail links to the staff member information div.

Let me know if you need any addition clarification.

**Update**: This answer is for a solution using SimpleModal

Comment: Reply after an appropriate answer was already provided and gave a unwarranted bump down for no reason without explanation.  NTM:  The link you provided is giving the same details as the initial post you bumped down.

Comment: "...so how do I go about doing this"  The question was asked for how to do it, not how do I use "Plug-in A to do this".  My answer did not deserve the bump down.

Comment: And I'll even go as far to say since you put a link to using a different component, I'll undo my bump if the same is done for your unwarranted bump.

Comment: Looks like I can't clear the down vote until the question is edited. Not sure why that is...