# How to create multiple Simple Modal dialogs in a page, one for each link?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am trying to create a gallery of videos with thumbnails. I have the first thumbnail working with SimpleModal at the correct height, but all of the other thumbnails keep opening the first modal box. How can I create separate modal boxes so different content shows up when different links are clicked?

Please help, I can feel this is 10x simpler than what I am trying.

Comment: I would suggest using Modal Box: http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$('img').click(function()
    {
        // create the div's popup
        $.('<div>')
            .html("whatever html included in the popup")
            .dialog({ 
                height: 200,
                width: 520,
                modal: false
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SO question/answer should provide you with the solution you are looking for, and it is SimpleModal specific:

[Multiple calls with Simple Modal OSX Style Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129006/multiple-calls-with-simple-modal-osx-style-dialog/2258297#2258297)