# Inserting Variable into DIV within a Javascript Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, simplemodal

Just to put it out there if I say the wrong lingo, I have literally less than 4 hours experience in Javascript for starters.  What I am trying to do is add a variable to the end of a predefined DIV that is in javascript.

For example here is the variable:

```
<?php 
    $n = rand(10e16, 10e20);
    $x = base_convert($n, 10, 36);
?>
```

Here is the variable in use:

```
<input type="button" name="osx<?php echo $x;?>" value="View" class="osx<?php echo $x;?>" id="osx<?php $x;?>"/>

<div id="osx-modal-content<?php echo $x;?>" style="display:none">
```

In the javascript function I currently have this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("[id^=osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $("[id^=osx-modal-content]").modal({OPTIONS});
```

And this:

```
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("[id^=osx-modal-content]" + $x, self.container).show();
```

Apparently Begins With is not the best solution. Since when an onclick event occurs it causes all DIVS on the page that begin with osx-modal-content to activate. So it needs to be fine tuned.

How would I add the variable to the javascript so its like....

```
$("osx" + $x).click(function (e) {
$("#osx-modal-content" + $x).modal({OPTIONS});
$("#osx-modal-content" + $x, self.container).show();
```

which would for example let's say $x = 12345 so Javascript would read it as.....

```
 $("osx12345")      etc..........
 $("#osx-modal-content12345")    etc.......
 $("#osx-modal-content12345", self.container   etc.......
```

Comment: Um, yes. What you wrote should work. Is something not working?

Comment: Is the code EXACTLY how you posted it? As you're click event in the second from last paragraph doesn't have a # in the jquery selector

Comment: Sorry guys, thought this would be enough info. The javascript is not inline with the code its in the footer and pulled when the page loads I guess?  I get this error when I inspect with Chrome: Uncaught ReferenceError: $x is not defined. You can view the full code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126931/bizarre-simplemodal-osx-actions-in-foreach-loop

Comment: I went ahead and unlinked the js and put the function inline with the code within the loop and still no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var osx = "osx<?php echo $x;?>";
</script>
```

Then you can use the osx variable in your jQuery selectors

Comment: Thanks for the answer standup, I'm not quite sure where I am to implement this? would you mind looking at the code here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126931/bizarre-simplemodal-osx-actions-in-foreach-loop

Comment: you can put it at the script tag, for example after you put the value on variable x, below you can put the code standup wrote then after your javascript can use the variable "osx", in short, you need to put the value of php on the variable of javascript.

<?php  $x = "12345" ;?>
<script>
     var osx = "<?php echo $x; ?>"
</script>

now you can access the value on javascript