# Multiple simplemodal's on one page - dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty, simplemodal

I am working on a project internally, and want to use simplemodal to display customer info, when clicked in the table where all the customers are listed.

This has however caused me some trouble, and therefore I am now asking you guys.

This is my code so far:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="customertable" class="sortable">
<thead>
    <tr class="odd">
        <th>Navn</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Postnummer</th>
        <th>By</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{foreach $results as $customer}
{strip}
   <tr class="{cycle values='even,odd'}">
      <td class="name" id='mousetracking' title={$customer.name}><a href="#" id="osx{$customer.customerid}">{$customer.name}</a></td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.phone}</td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.postcode}</td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.city}</td>
   </tr>
{/strip}
        <!-- modal content -->
        <div class="modalhidden">
            <div id="osx-modal-content{$customer.customerid}">
                <div id="osx-modal-title">Customer no #{$customer.customerid}</div>
                <div class="close"><a href="#" class="simplemodal-close">x</a></div>
                <div id="osx-modal-data">
                    <h2>Hello! I'm Customer no. #{$customer.customerid}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{/foreach}
</tbody>
</table>
Displaying {$total} records<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function addModal(x)
{
    $("osx" + x).addEvent("click", function(){
          var SM = new SimpleModal();
              SM.show({
                "title":"Title",
                "contents": $("#osx-modal-content" + x).html()
              });
        });

}
</script>
```

As you might have noticed, I am using smarty for the templating, which works fine.

Also, a single simplemodal works fine - but I want multiple of them with different content.

Question is, if this is a good idea, or if it should rather be on a separate page?

Please, tell if I am missing some information here - this is my first post :-)

Regards,
Frederik

**EDIT**

I now have this code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="customertable" class="sortable">
<thead>
    <tr class="odd">
        <th>Navn</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Postnummer</th>
        <th>By</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{foreach $results as $customer}
{strip}
   <tr class="{cycle values='even,odd'}">
      <td class="name" id='mousetracking' title={$customer.name}><a href="#" id="{$customer.customerid}">{$customer.name}</a></td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.phone}</td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.postcode}</td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.city}</td>
   </tr>
{/strip}
        <!-- modal content -->
        <!--<div class="modalhidden">-->
            <div id="modal_{$customer.customerid}">
                <div id="osx-modal-title_{$customer.customerid}">Customer no #{$customer.customerid}</div>
                <div class="close"><a href="#" class="simplemodal-close">x</a></div>
                <div id="osx-modal-data_{$customer.customerid}">
                    <h2>Hello! I'm Customer no. #{$customer.customerid}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--</div>-->
{/foreach}
</tbody>
</table>
Displaying {$total} records<br />
```

Together with this JS code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var OSX = {
        container: null,
        init: function () {
            $("a").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 

                $('#modal_' + this.id).modal({
                    overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                    containerId: 'osx-container',
                    closeHTML: null,
                    minHeight: 80,
                    opacity: 65, 
                    position: ['0',],
                    overlayClose: true,
                    onOpen: OSX.open,
                    onClose: OSX.close
                });
            });
        },
        open: function (d) {
            var self = this;
            self.container = d.container[0];
            d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $('#modal_' + this.id, self.container).show();
                var title = $('#osx-modal-title_' + this.id, self.container);
                title.show();
                d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var h = $('#osx-modal-data_' + this.id, self.container).height()
                            + title.height()
                            + 20; // padding
                        d.container.animate(
                            {height: h}, 
                            200,
                            function () {
                                $("div.close", self.container).show();
                                $('#osx-modal-data_' + this.id, self.container).show();
                            }
                        );
                    }, 300);
                });
            })
        },
        close: function (d) {
            var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
            d.container.animate(
                {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
                500,
                function () {
                    self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
                }
            );
        }
    };

    OSX.init();

});
```

and the original jquery.simplemodal.js

My only problem now is, that it loads the modal with the right div, but that div is hidden..

Comment: "... This has however caused me some trouble...," what kind of troubles? Also putting together an example might be better.

Comment: The trouble is, that I cannot get the above code to work, and I cannot figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Is this Eric Martin's simplemodal? Having used it, there is no `SimpleModal` prototype in his code base. You use `$.modal` to open a dialog.

Comment: @jamietre yes it is his simplemodal. I didn't really understand the rest of your comment, sorry.

Comment: Your code says `SM = new SimpleModal()` which would not do anything in the absence of some other code. So I guess that must be an object you've created that wraps the API. So what does your `SimpleModal` object look like?

Comment: @jamietre I am of course including the jquery.js - jquery.simplemodal.js and the osx.js files in the page - just not shown in the example above.

Comment: ok, so where in the simplemodal documentation: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ does it say to write code like `SM = new SimpleModal()`? That is not how it's used. Unless there is code *that is not part of Eric Martin's simplemodal* outside of what you're showing us here, I think you have a pretty basic usage problem.

Comment: That was some code I found elsewhere in here - just tried it, and didnt seem to work properly.
I have however found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2129006/1352083) - how should that be implemented in my script, and would it work?

Comment: @jamietre - I have updated the original post with some new code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. I managed to fix it myself.

Ended up with this code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="customertable" class="sortable">
<thead>
    <tr class="odd">
        <th>Navn</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Postnummer</th>
        <th>By</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{foreach $results as $customer}
{strip}
   <tr class="{cycle values='even,odd'}">
      <td class="name" id='mousetracking' title={$customer.name}><div id="basic-modal"><a href="#" id="{$customer.customerid}">{$customer.name}</a></div></td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.phone}</td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.postcode}</td>
      <td class="data">{$customer.city}</td>
   </tr>
{/strip}
{/foreach}
</tbody>
</table>
{foreach $results as $customer}
{strip}
        <!-- modal content -->
        <div id="basic-modal-content_{$customer.customerid}" style="display:none;" width="600px">
            <h3>{$customer.name}</h3>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="150px;">Adresse</td>
                    <td>{$customer.address1}<br />{$customer.postcode}&nbsp;{$customer.city}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150px;">Telefon</td>
                    <td>{$customer.phone}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150px;">Fax</td>
                    <td>{$customer.fax}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150px;">Email</td>
                    <td>{$customer.email}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150px;">Website</td>
                    <td>{$customer.web}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br /><br />
            <h4>Server Setup</h4>
            <code>{$customer.Server_setup}</code>
        </div>
{/strip}
{/foreach}
Displaying {$total} records<br />
```

Together with this javascript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal a').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content_' + this.id).modal({
            overlayClose:true
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

And it works like a charm.

Thanks for all the input.